# Editor to record user input and play it like a movie

Tags: text-editor

I need a code editor similar to CodeMirror  https://codemirror.net which can record user sequence of writing code and can replay it.I require it for developing online examination with functionality to watch how candidates solve the problem online.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier and better for you to just record the whole screen?

Comment: @Puddler, that will create a large file..Most likely the video quality has to be really good in order to see the text.

Comment: @tanjir , I got a example application URL : https://www.interviewzen.com/. But unable to find out how may i can implement it.